# creating a sql column updating it

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a new column in a table. I want to make it not nullable. And I don't want to use a default constraint.

I tried the following query. But it fails.

Please correct me here or suggest if a better option exists.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UCBCluster]  
ADD PBXClusterId INT NULL;

UPDATE [dbo].[UCBCluster] 
SET PBXClusterId = 0 
WHERE PBXClusterId IS NULL;

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UCBCluster] 
ALTER COLUMN PBXClusterId INT NOT NULL;
```

Error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Invalid column name 'PBXClusterId'.

Thanks

Comment: I have tried it with sqlfiddle and your query works fine. Which line is line 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo have to keep default costraint then only you can change to not null

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UCBCluster]
add constraint cnt_column Default '' for PBXClusterId

ALTER TABLE tb_TableName
ALTER COLUMN PBXClusterId int NOT NULL
```

Comment: I dint want to go for default constraint. I wanted to make it a mandatory field.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run all of this in a single batch, because SQL Server will parse it at the start of execution, and at that time, no `PBXClusterId` column exists yet.

You need to run this in **three separate batches** - either by just highlighting it in Management Studio, or if you want to run it as one, you need to put `GO` delimiters between your steps:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UCBCluster]  
ADD PBXClusterId INT NULL;
GO;

UPDATE [dbo].[UCBCluster] 
SET PBXClusterId = 0 
WHERE PBXClusterId IS NULL;
GO;

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UCBCluster] 
ALTER COLUMN PBXClusterId INT NOT NULL;
GO;
```

It is generally not a good idea to run DDL statements (data definition language - statements to *modify* your database *structure*) and DML statements (data manipulation language - adding or updating data) in the same batch of SQL statement in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UCBCluster]  ADD  PBXClusterId INT NOT NULL Default '0';
```

Comment: I dint want to go for default constraint. I wanted to make it a mandatory field.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Check Constraint

> I wanted to make it a mandatory field

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UCBCluster] ALTER COLUMN 
PBXClusterId INT CHECK (PBXClusterId IS NOT NULL);
```